# Destroying an object on the stage issue

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a simple Tower Defense Shooting game via the help of an online tutorial. The tutorial doesn't address an issue though.

This code is supposed to remove a bullet fired once it leaves the stage, but the bullet is only being removed upon leaving through the top or left sides of the stage.

My understanding is that the `stageWidth/Height` are supposed to handle the top and left and the `<0` handles the bottom and right. I cannot see anything that would be an issue. Can anyone see why it isn't working for the bottom or right sides of the stage?

```
if (bullet.x < 0 || bullet.x > stage.stageWidth || bullet.y < 0 || bullet.y > stage.stageHeight){
            bullet.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBullet);
            bullet.parent.removeChild(bullet);
            bullet = null;
            }
```

Comment: (0,0) is top left, (stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight) is bottom right, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bullet's coordinate system isn't necessarily the same as the stage's-- are they attached to the stage or maybe some other movieClip?

I'd suggest debugging, or adding trace statements, to see what the bullet's coordinates, and the stageWidth and Height are in the above code:

```
trace("bullet.x="+bullet.x+", stage.stageWidth="+stage.stageWidth);
```

Comment: The trace showed me what was happening. Turns out the bullets were being destroyed, but the stage was expanding to the edge of the window on the bottom and right sides, so I couldn't tell that they were. Thanks a bunch